# How to send a encrypted string along with a base url through webview?

Tags: android, encryption, webview, payment-gateway

I'm implementing a payment gateway in my project. Now I have a base url and along with that some encrypted parameters like amount merchant id and all those stuffs.

So when the encryption completes I'm supposed to open it in a webview. If I try to concatenate the strings it doesn't work.

I got this info that while implementing the same for webpage they just use post method and the payment gateway worked. But how to open the same in webview in android device?

I tried this way:

```
wvSBIBuddy.loadUrl(url);
wvSBIBuddy.loadData(urlCreateOrder.toString(), "application/json", null);
```

Didn't work. Tried this:

```
wvSBIBuddy.loadDataWithBaseURL(url,urlCreateOrder,"text/html", null, ENCODING_KEY);
wvSBIBuddy.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "HtmlViewer");
```

any hint what might work?

EDIT:
Is it possible to add some refer headers along with the encrypted detail?
I looked into the webview class it seems encrypted data and refer both can't be send at the same time, still asking any way to do that?

Comment: Are you sure that you need to do it in a WebView? A POST is usually performed using HttpUrlConnection or another Java HTTP client implementation.

Comment: No that is what i came to know from the java development team, so anyway its possible in android im good with it. I have a base url and some encrypted data, how to open that in webview?

Answer (score 1):

`postUrl` takes a byte array, so I don't know if just decoding your string with the default charset into a byte array will work right.  But this is how you do a POST:

```
wvSBIBuddy.postUrl(url, urlCreateOrder.getBytes());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried it but still it doesn't seem to work, had some discussion with my backend team, and trying to find if we can add some refer headers along with the encrypted detail, but it seems encrypted data and refer both can't be send at the same time, any way to do that?

Comment: To get access to the request headers, you would have to use HttpURLConnection.   You could try capturing the response to the request and showing that with `loadData`, but then the complexity is starting to get out of hand.

Comment: No no im implementing a payment gateway so the wallet login and everything has to start from webview only can't post something and show the response. Still now the payment gateway wallet login page is not showing its giving error even if I encrypt the whole thing correctly.